# JavaScript add onclick from script with paramenter

Tags: javascript, onclick

I need to add a onclic event to a element inside a script.
I did this:

```
element.onclick=function;
```

But i need to send a value too with the function, something like

```
element.onclick=function(value);
```

But that doesnt work.
Could you help me please?

Comment: you have to use `.bind(null, value)`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `function()`, it will call function. If you want to pass a value to a function assignment, you should use `.bind(context, arguments)`.

Following snippet depicts the same

```js
var value = 10;
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = notify.bind(null, value);

function notify(value){
  alert(value);
  value++
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">test</button>
```

As pointed out by @Dmitri Pavlutin, here it will be a static binding. If value is changed, it will not be reflected in event call.

Comment: What happens if the `value` changes to another value? And later triggering the click will still indicate the old value.

Comment: Value will not be reflected. If such requirement is there, its better to fetch value inside handler itself or create a function that does processing and fetch value in handler and pass it to function

Answer (score 0):

Just create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
var value = 1;
element.onclick = function() {
  myHandler(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this multiple ways even without using any library. One of them is using attributes which you have to set on the element.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('click');

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var msg = this.getAttribute('data-attr');
  alert(msg);
})
```

```css
#click {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="click" data-attr="data"> 
  Click me
</div>
```

Another approach that might work is actually using closure:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = notify("Passed");

function notify(value){
  return function() {
    alert(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the parameter is an object?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin: This specific script wont work with object. But it can be done using same approach

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin: I think the second approach will work for objects

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of confusing here so I'll add a more general comment for those still getting to grips with Events.

A `click` event is generally associated with a user interaction - they click on something and something else happens. So you need to:

1. define an element
2. define a "click" function
3. associated the function with the element
4. gather any information to be used and/or passed to other parts of the script when the element is clicked.
5. do something with that information.

If you wish to provide a method which allows your script to click the target element rather than the user then this example may help:

**Example HTML**

```
<div id="click-div" data-text="Hello World">
   <!-- ...content... -->
</div>
```

**Example JavaScript**

```
function getTheData(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    /* function called by 'theClickFunction()' 
       arg1 (= 'click-div')
       arg2 (= 'Hello World')
       arg3 (= '123.45) */
}

function theClickFunction(event) {
   /* this function is called whenever
       the target element is clicked - either 
       by a user or by JavaScript */
   var divID = event.target.id; /* 'click-div' */
   var hello = event.target.getAttribute('data-text'); /* "Hello World" */
   var extra = 123.45;
   getTheData(divID, hello, extra);
}

function clickTheDiv() {
   /* this function clicks the element 
      from this JavaScript instead of
      a user */
   var cDiv = document.getElementById('click-div');
   cDiv.click(); /* <-- element clicked! */
}

window.onload = function() {
   /* add event listener to the target
      element when the page has loaded */
   var targetElem = document.getElementById('click-div');
   targetElem.addEventListener(
      'click', theClickFunction, false
   );
};
```

Starting from the bottom:

1. Add an event listener to the target element so that it will do something - in this case it will fire the function `theClickFunction()` whenever a `click` occurs.
2. Add the function `clickTheDiv()` that will allow us to click the target element with JavaScript.
3. Add the function `theClickFunction()` which is called whenever the target element is clicked.  This function automatically receives an 'event' argument (you can call it whatever you like in your code but 'event', or often just 'e', acts as a reminder that you are dealing with Events).  You can think of this as a reference back to the `html`-element that fired the function.  It allows us gather information about and from that element with the inbuilt `target` method.  Here the element's **id** and **data-text** attributes are collected along with a 'extra' item of information.  This is then passed to...
4. ... the function `getTheData()` which will do something with everything we've gathered together.

Whenever a user clicks `<div id="click-div">` the function `theClickFunction` will be called.  We can call that function for them by adding the simple function call `clickTheDiv();` somewhere else in our script.

Of course, all of this can be condensed and doesn't have to be structured exactly like this.  I've only done this here to give a clearer view about what is going on.

See also:

- [Quirksmode - Introduction to
  Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)
- [MDN - Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [MDN - Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)
- [W3C - DOM Event Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/)

Answer (score -1):

Well at least you have to define what shall happen, if the function (so the event on click) is called.

Try something like this:

```
element.onclick= function()
{
    //Your event here
    console.log("hey there");
}
```

Or you make it with jQuery:

```
$(yourElement).click(function(e)
{
    //Your event here
    console.log("hey there");
});
```